# Move data up a row if preceding row is empty in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to develop a macro that will allow me to cut and paste a value or text from one row to the upper row, if the upper row is empty in a some specific columns. (If possible, I'd like to delete the empty rows after that.)

```
4137274 20120604   41.6    10.83   Tolerance exceeded
4137279 20120604                   Tax code missing
                   55.9    -0.04    
4137271 20120604
                  111.8   -11.26   Tolerance exceeded
4137325 20120604                   Tax code missing
                  130.72    0   
4139318 20120605   65.36    0      Tax code missing
4139114 20120605
                  223.6   -22.54   Tolerance exceeded
4139279 20120605
                  111.8   111.8    Tolerance exceeded
4139151 20120605   65.36   65.36   GR does not exist
4140802 20120605   27.95   -0.02   Tax code missing
4140732 20120605   27.95   27.95   GR does not exist
```

As you can see above, some of the prices are in the next row. I have to work with a large amount of data where it is not possible to cut and paste all of them manually. Is there a way to do this, with a macro or otherwise?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But while we can help, we won't do your job. So please show us [what you have already built](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you are stuck or what doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be consecutive empty cells (in a column)? If so, would you want the value below to populate all the empty rows above (until you reach a non-empty cell) or just the first one? Big hint: select all the data, then filter the blanks on your specific column(s) and try using a formula to get the proceeding cell value(s). Copy & paste as values. Then, filter on the blanks for the other columns to get the rows you want to delete. Again, let us know what you try and what works for you. If you find the solution yourself, then you can answer your own question, as well! :)

Comment: @JMax - nice article on *what have you tried*.

Answer (score 2):

Without writing the macro for you, here is some pseudo-code and some pointers:

1. Move the selection to cell A1
2. Test for a empty cell

   1. if empty, execute `Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` and increment an `empty counter`
   2. if not empty, zero `empty counter` and move down
3. When `empty counter` reaches 10 (or some number to signal that no more data exists in that column), break out of the loop.
4. Move the selection to B1 and repeat
5. Repeat for column C, etc.

Instead of doing a cut/paste to move values, doing the `Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` will discard the empty cell and move everything under it upwards by one cell.  It will not affect the other columns if you only have ***one*** cell selected.